# Using LowProfileImageLoader to load byte[] image from server in WP7 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, wcf-data-services

I want to use LowProfileImageLoader in my WP7 app but the problem is that I am getting the image data from the server in byte[] using my WCF Web Service so I don't have image URI. Can somebody suggests me how to use LowProfileImageLoader with my current image data?

Comment: There is no point. From what I see, main advantage of LowProfileImageLoader is downloading the images in an orderly fashion and from what you say I understand you have them downloaded already.

Comment: @Agent_L Yes, currently in my app I have downloaded the images which takes a lot of time to load. So, I want to use LowProfileImageLoader to download the image in the background gradually when I scroll down the Image ListBox.

Comment: I don't understand. You have them downloaded and you want to download them again?

Comment: ListBox is aready doing all that job - it calls `get` only on visible items, as you scroll.

Comment: @Agent_L What I want is to show the download completed images gradually one after another like the one in Google Web album app. I don't want to wait for all the images to be downloaded. Those who are loaded first should fill up their respective places in my list box.

Comment: Then you have to return some dummy value on first `get` (null or a placeholder image), then make timed calls to `NotifyPropertyChanged` so UI will call `get` again and return proper image this time.

Comment: @Agent_L That's exactly what I want but don't know how to get it. Can you please give a sample code of placing Image Place Holder before loading the image?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16534/discussion-between-agent-l-and-sana)

Answer (score 0):

Put the bytes in a `MemoryStream` and then use `setSource()` member of `BitmapImage` to get the image into your UI.